# Symfony2 Monolog configure to use raven handler (Sentry)

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I want to use sentry to evaluate possible errors, exceptions, etc.

I tried to use the KunstmaanSentryBundle and it's great to catch all kind of errors like undefined functions and so on, but I want to define my own Monolog channel with it's own handler, but unfortunately I haven't found documentation about it.

`config.yml` would be something like:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    sentry:
        type:  stream
        level: error
        //Log to database parameter (raven for sentry)
```

Does anybody knows the right configuration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is part of `config_prod.yml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped_main

        sentry:
            type:  raven
            dsn:   'http://user:pass@url/1'
            level: notice

        # Groups
        grouped_main:
            type:    group
            members: [sentry, streamed_main]

        # Streams
        streamed_main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: error
```

Enjoy! :)

Comment: it works thanks, monolog 2.4.* and symfony 2.3.* are required

Comment: Actually Symfony 2.2+ is needed. I know, because we have it on one project now :)

Comment: Just a heads up, be careful what version of the `raven/raven` library you use in your `composer.json`, because if you are using an older version of Sentry then you will encounter API version mismatching issues, and the logging will just fail silently

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to add this as a comment on the accepted answer, but not enough rep, so:

From `\Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration` :

"Possible handler types and related configurations (brackets indicate optional params):

- raven:

  - dsn: connection string
  - client_id: Raven client custom service id (optional)
  - [level]: level name or int value, defaults to DEBUG
  - [bubble]: bool, defaults to true

"

Example config would be:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        sentry:
            type: raven
            dsn: '%sentry_api_key%'
            client_id: 'your.raven.client.custom.service.id'
            level: notice
            bubble: false
```