# Symfony MonologBundle: Use a sentry processor inside Symfony's MonologBundle

Tags: symfony, sentry, monolog

I've configured a Sentry handler for Monolog via config.yml. Now I need to filter out some data from the log data. The data is added in sentry's raven_handler. Thus I need to use a Sentry processor to filter it out. Monolog processors are working before the log goes to the sentry.

I do not find a way to pass a Sentry processor via Monolog's .yml configuration.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Monolog configure to use raven handler (Sentry)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115076/symfony2-monolog-configure-to-use-raven-handler-sentry)